# how to ignore service restart request via sudoers config in linux

Tags: linux, service, suse, sudoers

Is there any way I can ignore service restart requests coming to my service in SuSe linux?
I tried setting the chkconfig  off. But it didn't work. I tried editing sudoers file t block all the users from executing that service. But the changes are not taking into effect. I login from nother terminal and still able to start/stop the service. Say as below:

```
root ALL=/etc/init.d, !/etc/init.d/<my_service>
```

Basically service  restart/start/stop should have no impact. I mean the service should be off for a brief period of time and then turn it on later. I can make change in my service start code, but that is a last option for me. I'm looking for any option to configure in my linux OS itself.

Any suggestions?